# Extracting tableViewCell Widths in an Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I woukld like to form an Array which contains the widths of each label inside the customTableCell. As illustrated in the attached image, I managed to extract all the widths I am interested in but they are not all in the same array. Any idea how can I extrac t all the widths in ONE array?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your  array only once, not every time `tableView(_: UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` is called. This can be achieved by moving the declaration of  your array, on line 83, to somewhere outside of the function scope, but inside the class scope, like line 92. When you do that, `cellsWitdhsArray` will become a class variable, or an attribute, that can be accessed from  anywhere inside the class

Comment: Thanks alot, your suggestion sorted out my problem.

Comment: Important to also take a look at @GntlmnBndt 's answer, as it solves a problem my answer did  not address

Answer (score 1):

@BrunoPastre is correct, but appending is also not the way to assign the values in the array. This function will be run many times for some cells, as you scroll up and down. You will end up with the same widths listed many times at different places in the array.

You should create the array with the right dimension, then assign them as `cellsWidthsArray[indexPath.row] = cell.cellTextLabel.frame.size.width`.

Answer (score 0):

That method is called once per cell, if you declare a local variable `cellsWidthArray` its not going to persist across multiple calls of that function.

What you need is to "save" this array somewhere that isn't a local, temporary scope. The best way to do this is to save it as a property on the class.

I can see in your code you already have another array thats a property: `tableViewRowsInsideSectionsArray`. Scroll up to (hopefully) the very top of the class declaration in the same scope add your own `cellsWidthArray`.

It should look something like

```
class MyViewController {
    ...
    private var cellsWidthArray: [CGFloat] = []
    ...
```

That way that local array isn't lost every time the function ends - it's owned by the view controller and is available anywhere within that class as long as that class exists.

HOWEVER, it may not work as you expect because another issue with that method (`tableView(cellForRowAt:)` is that it's only called when a cell is being displayed (visible on the screen). And it will be called multiple times if you scroll a cell off and back on the screen.

You can solve potential duplication by creating a dictionary where the key is something uniquely identifying the cell (it seems like its just going to be the text here) and the value is the width. Something like:

```
class MyViewController {
    ...
    private var cellsWidthDictionary: [String: CGFloat] = [:]
    ...
    func tableView(cellForRowAt:) { // I didn't feel like typing it all out
        ...
        cellsWidthDictionary[theTextYouAreUsing] = width
```

But you now have another issue, the way you are getting the width, accessing the frame of the label just after you set the text, might not actually be correct. This function just prepares the cell, auto layout and frame adjustments might happen later.
A simple one line solution one might be tempted to do is to force a layout on the cell, after setting the text on the label, something like:

`cell.cellTextLabel.sizeToFit()` or `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`

that will just adjust the frame of the label to perfectly wrap the existing content.. but a much better solution would be to actually calculate it..

You could use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-size
something like

```
let labelSize = (label.text?.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: label.font.fontName , size: label.font.pointSize)!]))
```

then accessing `labelSize.width`

You're still left with the problem of only having that function called when a cell is about to be displayed on the screen. You can either manually scroll through every cell to build that table if you're using it for debugging/testing/informative purposes. But otherwise you would need to do something else...

Fortunately, Swift has a function that calculates the size a string would take - you just have to make sure you specify the text/font/size/any other styling elements. I pointed it out above... you can just iterate through all the strings that you're feeding into the cells and generate the dictionary right then and there as soon as you get the data.

Keep in mind this assumes a single line, if you have a max width for the label or other constraints that would cause the text to be cut off you would need to be even more explicit - I encourage you to google how to calculate the size of a label based off your needs if so.

Comment: Thank you Gadu for the detailed reply. My problem is solved. What I would like to do eventually is to find out the maximum cell width in the Array and then set the tableView width equivalent to the maximum cell width in the Array I extracted out. However, it is not as easy as I expected as I am running into App cycle issues now :/